# How trigger Azure timer function every 90 seconds?

Tags: javascript, azure, timer, azure-functions

there some tutorials that will show you how use Azure Timer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) and [here](https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/) (in second one you should see limitation too)

but I need to trigger it every 90 seconds (one minute and 30 seconds).
I used these ways but seems not work:

```
*/30 */1 * * * * //will trigger every 30 seconds
*/90 * * * * * //will trigger every 60 seconds
30 * * * * * //will trigger each minute start at second 30
```

then How I can trigger it each 90 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to create two functions with same body, but different cron expressions:

```
0 0/3 * * * *  // 00:00 03:00 06:00...
30 1/3 * * * * // 01:30 04:30 07:30...
```

Each of those function will run every 3 minutes, with 90 seconds shift in between. It probably makes sense to reuse bodies by extracting it into a helper function, and then call it from both functions.

Another option is to create a single function that fires every 30 seconds, do the check if current time is proper multiple of 90 seconds, and return immediately otherwise.

Comment: It's not possible to add two "CRON expression" at the same time.
then I can't understand what you mean...
if I start using two function, I should call another one each 30 seconds!
and in second function, I should manage each 3 triggers to reach the 90 seconds! I even can do this by one function (and I should use database or something like that of-course). seems it's a way, but I think there should be some better and easier way

Comment: @RezaAmya My suggestion is to create 2 functions with same body, but different cron expressions. Each of those function will run every 3 minutes, with 1 m 30 sec shift in between.

Comment: This is not a good solution, since it promotes logic duplication and will poorly scale if needed. It is not well designed. See my proposed answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible using CRON (as [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171619/mikhail) mentioned). However, it is **highly** not recommended to duplicate logic between components (different Functions in this case). It is actually the Function's parallel of a known [bad-smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/duplicate-code). Generally, for any domain, this isn't the ideal solution (I guess the reason is clear).

I would suggest one Function that holds all of the logic, which will be triggered by other Functions, which will hold minimum logic that is independent of the actual program logic.
You can choose whatever suits you best, this can be either via HTTP triggers, Queues or others.
Then, 2 (or any number in fact) Functions will trigger this Function using its trigger.

For example, you can create one Function with an HTTP trigger, that holds all of the logic.
Then, create 2 Functions, each triggered using a different CRON expression. both will just call trigger the 'logical' function using an HTTP call.

For your specific need of 90 seconds, you can use these CRON expressions that were already suggested (one per 'trigger' Function)

```
0 0/3 * * * * 
30 1/3 * * * *
```

Comment: You are still creating 2 functions with same body, so it's the same answer :) I didn't suggest to copy-paste the 50-line bodies. In the world of pre-compiled functions they will probably be 1-liners calling the same private method.

Comment: Creating 2 or more "triggering" functions that just act as triggers to another function with the actual logic, is not the same as having 2 (or more) functions with the same logic duplicated. You now expand your original suggestion, to having both functions call the same private method, which was not mentioned in your original answer. Since the original question asked to run a Function (and not some private method) every 90 questions, my suggestion still holds and answers the exact specifications with the option to scale for future modifications and more triggers.